# Stress and suffering felt when I touch the right frontal lobe of my forehead

Tags: meditation, suffering, science

I was wondering if this could be scientific or dhamma proof of the eminence of suffering coming from a physical and mental root. If you touch and rub the front right part of your forehead you can feel the dukkha or suffering from rubbing it. You will even feel a residual paste on your skin that contains stress and suffering.

What is this and do other people experience this? Is this actual physical scientific proof of suffering and Buddhism?

Comment: I don't think everyone experiences that. Please consult a medical doctor.

Comment: Two months too late.

Comment: No, that is your attachment. If you weren't attached to your body you can even self immolate yourself bearing all pain like the monk Thich Quang Duc. The key is to not give a  about anything including the body.

Answer (score 2):

In Buddhism, the word 'dukkha' is used in three different ways, having three different meanings:

1. Dukkha-vedana; meaning painful, unpleasant or uncomfortable sensations/feelings.
2. Dukkha-lakkhana; meaning the unsatisfactory/unpleasurable characteristic of impermanent things
3. Pancupadanakhandha-dukkha; meaning the suffering or stressfulness of egoistic attachment towards the five aggregates

The only 'dukkha' Buddhist enlightenment ends is the 3rd type of dukkha above; which is the dukkha of egoistic attachment.

The residual discomfort of touching the forehead is the unpleasant feeling sensation of the 1st type of dukkha. Eradicating this type of dukkha is not the purpose of Buddhism and not the type of dukkha to be "fully understood", "verified" or "known for certain" ("pariññāta").

When [SN 56.11](https://suttacentral.net/sn56.11/en/bodhi?reference=main&highlight=false) says dukkha is to be fully understood, this refers to the 3rd type of dukkha:

> Now this, bhikkhus, is the noble truth of suffering: birth is
> suffering, aging is suffering, illness is suffering, death is
> suffering; union with what is displeasing is suffering; separation
> from what is pleasing is suffering; not to get what one wants is
> suffering; **in brief, the five aggregates subject to clinging [attachment] are
> suffering... This noble truth of suffering is to be *fully understood***
> (*pariññāta*).

Comment: if one is no longer attached to worldly things wouldn't the dukkha associated with their impermanent characteristic also end?

Comment: No because dukkha here means something cannot bring lasting happiness. Dukkha here is not a state of mind but is an inherent characteristic of all conditioned things, such as a rock or tree. If you are unenlightened, food cannot bring lasting happiness because if you keep eating food you will get bloated & vomit, such as in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n_z_mnSSmQg

Comment: Therefore when a person is enlightened, everything they experience (except Nibbana) is impermanent, unsatisfactory (dukkha) & non-self. When a person is not enlightened, they cannot see the dukkha in all conditioned things.  They think the most beautiful woman in the world, a luxury home or a luxury can bring them happiness. But when a person is enlightened they see the dukkha in conditioned things. They understand there is nothing in a luxury car than can bring happiness. The dukkha is in the luxury car. It is like a rock. There is nothing in a rock than can supply the nutriments for life.

Comment: ok fine. but this super-seeing must be felt to some extent.  so compassion is like small dukkha.  also, are you implying that nirvana is being turned off and on?

Comment: The super-seeing results in disenchantment & dispassion, per the suttas (SN 22.59) https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/sn/sn22/sn22.059.mend.html). Nibbana is not a state without vedana (feelings; Iti 44 https://suttacentral.net/iti44/en/ireland?reference=none&highlight=false). Nirvana is not being turned on & off. Best to study more. Kind regards

Comment: thanks for your input.  not sure, but i think it is wrong to say the arhant *experiences* 3 marks. they experience nirvana

Comment: +1 for your answer, and nice video in example in the comments. Lol. The first two dukkhas come from there being a body. The third dukkha comes from mind (aggregates), however, the perception of physical pain can change, but it's still painful.

Comment: @Max dukkha is dukkha.  the maya dukkha is the what buddha is fixing

Comment: @blue_ego it is 100% wrong to think it is wrong to say the arhant experiences 3 marks. The suttas say in many places it is experiencing the 3 marks that causes arahantship.